# multiple sessionId in credentials

Tags: sonos

I use sessionId authentication method, and it seems as if Sonos devices kept more than one sessionId for my service. Basically the sessionId passed in the Credentials header is not always the sessionId generated with the latest getSessionId but sometimes the one generated two getSessionId ago. How is that possible? What can I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

So it is possible for every controller and player in a user's system to have different sessionIds and this behavior is expected. The latest sessionId does not invalidate previously created sessionIDs automatically. Please see the documentation located here: http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/82. Multiple id's can be generated based on the same valid set of login credentials.

Comment: Thanks. It'd be useful then to mention this in the documentation.